# How to extract data from column and insert into an array and add the values

Tags: php, sql-server-2016

Database:

```
ID | CID |    HOURS
1  | 201 |  8, 8, 8, 8
2  | 201 |  2, 4, 7, 5
3  | 201 |  4, 3, 7, 1
```

How can I extract the values in the HOURS column and add the values to produce the results of on a HTML table:

```
   TOTAL HOURS: 14  |  15  |  22  | 14
```

I am assuming that the values in Hours column need to be inserted into an array?  So, I did a while loop and exploded the results and got the following:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
    $hours = explode(', ', $hours)
}
```

I do a print_r($hours, 1) and get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 8
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 1
)
```

How do I loop this to do the calculation?

Comment: Do a query, use `explode()` to separate the comma-delimited list into an array, and then loop over all the arrays calculating the totals.

Comment: Have you *actually* got comma delimeted values stored in a single column? That's your biggest issue; these values should be in rows - your output is then a simple `sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the comma-delimeted data being an anti-pattern, it's *possible* to return your aggregated values in a single query without needing to loop over anything by using `string_split`, the basics of which are:

```
select
  Sum(case col when 1 then v end),
  Sum(case col when 2 then v end),
  Sum(case col when 3 then v end),
  Sum(case col when 4 then v end)
from (
    select v, row_number() over(partition by id order by id) col
    from t
    cross apply(
    select Cast(value as int)v from String_Split(t.hours,',')
    )v
)v
```

[demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=50c3380805d30f5949415a1bac06f4c2)

Comment: This worked, but can you explain the code?  I've used the case statement before, but not like this, it's very interesting.

Comment: It's referred to as a *conditional sum* or *conditional case*, after string_split returns the data split out per-id with the comma separated list as one value per row with a row number to indicate which column the value is in, we then conditionally sum the values according to which column, using the row number as the column indicator. THere's one small caveat in that sql server should really provide the row numbering as part of the string_split function and according to the documentation the order is not 100% guaranteed, but I've used this a *lot* and never once seen it not to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, truly appreciate it.